# CSS set side menu width based screen width in pixel

Tags: html, css

Currently I have set the left menu of page with percentage 20% of body width. However, I'm using this to make the menu stay the same place when I zoom the page. Now i want to use pixel for it,but i know when using fixed pixel, if we change screen,the menu width still stay the same and it look imbalance.

I have searched around and found 2 ways : using media query or using javascript trick. If i using query, i have to repeat for many different resolutions. The Javascript way seem to be dirty.

So, is there any other way to dinamycally change the size of element base on screen size with pixel ? I see web like Facebook or W3school have the left menu in pixel,and when i open the page in a bigger screen,the width increase. How can i do like that ?

[image]

Comment: Percentage should do the work. Your menu may be in a div which has pixel defined width. It would be easier to help if you could share your code.

Comment: percentage width with min-width and max-width will help you

Comment: Yes,percentage is ok except when i try to zoom the page,it doesn't change size.I have see web like Facebook or W3school have the left menu in pixel,and when i open the page in a bigger screen,the width increase.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu{
background-color : red;
width : 20%;
height:500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This code works! It shrinks the box width as I shrink the browser size.

Comment: yeah,but if you zoom it (ctrl + mouse scroll),the menu width stay the same. It's look weird because when every thing is bigger,the menu width doesn't change.That why i want to change to pixel.

Comment: Then use `min-width` and/or `max-width`, as @kiranvj suggests.